# KnockoutJS bindings not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Ok getting frustrated on this one.... Using knockoutJS to do some visual interaction stuff.

What I have is a button that is going to make an AJAX call to validate some data. That call sends back a CanProceed property as well as an object that represents other view settings. The code works when I set CanProceed(true) this turns on a DIV that has more DIVs inside it, each of those visibility properties are bound to a Permissions.AllowXXX that is set from the server.

See the fiddle for an example

http://jsfiddle.net/RcCAx/

What I want to have happen is when I get the Permissions from the server I should be able to tell knockout about the object and have the page UI update but its not working. If I declare the observable first (like with the CanProceed property) it works, but if I try and use the ko.mapping.fromJS(serverdataobject) here its not updating stuff that was bound to it earlier.

Help......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RcCAx/2/) for a solution. The key here is to have Permissions be an observable

Comment: Ok now how does the "with: " binding actually make this happen?

Comment: It's not necessary, I used it mostly to avoid messy binding strings like here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RcCAx/3/). I also had to change `self.Permissions = ko.observable()` to `self.Permissions = ko.observable({})`, otherwise the `Permissions()` in the binding strings would be undefined